# String.format()

Tags: java, c++, format

"%11.2lf" of C++ is equivalent to ?

You guys have any resource that shows the equivalent formats for both Java and C++?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion


says everything :)

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: The Java equivalent is `"%11.2f"`.

In C's `printf()` (but not `scanf()`), `%f` and `%lf are equivalent; Both take a double argument.`

In Java's `Formatter.format()`, `%f` is legal but `%lf` is not.  `%f` works for `Float`, Double and BigDecimal values.

Answer (score 2):

C++ [cpplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Java [Sun javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Boost Format. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#syntax

It has the basically the same formatters as printf().
But they are type safe and can be used on streams.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the equivalent in Java.